# Cellulose - why is it fibrous and not granular?

Tags: cell-biology, carbohydrates

I was reading a book where it said that the 1 - 4 Glycosidic bond of the Beta Glucose meant that cellulose is `fibrous` and not `granular`.

First, what does it mean to be `granular` and why is not `granular` unlike Amylose?

Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Ive been wrong several times before so take my word with a a heavy "grain" of salt. (pun get it? :D )    But Cellulose is a linear polymer and therefore makes a fiber. I guess the linear in this case implies fiber.   Amylose has a helical structure to it i think. Here is an image i found that shows the difference. http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-WpoQllkgT3M/Ug51lW5oEPI/AAAAAAAACCI/vuJmfjHCk0Q/s1600/3starchcellulose.gif

Comment: @RoSiv Thanks a million! Please respond with your answer so I can mark you up and tick you! Good pun too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool I got something right :D

Cellulose is a linear polymer and therefore makes a fiber. I guess the linear in this case implies fiber. Amylose has a helical structure to it i think. Here is an image I found that shows the difference.

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-WpoQllkgT3M/Ug51lW5oEPI/AAAAAAAACCI/vuJmfjHCk0Q/s1600/3starchcellulose.gif]